# OOP Mysqli num_rows allways return 0

Tags: php

I'm trying to count the rows returned from the database. When i run this code this will give me return of 1 row which contains a username and password but when i try to count the rows it allways give back zero even tho database is actually returning rows.

`$row_count =$stmt -> num_rows` only returns 0.

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare
("SELECT username, password FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($returned_username, $returned_password);   
$stmt->fetch();

$row_count = $stmt -> num_rows;
echo $row_count;

echo $returned_username;
echo "<br />";
echo $returned_password;

$stmt -> close();   
$mysqli ->close();
```

Comment: Have you checked [the only User Comment](http://uk3.php.net/mysqli-num-rows) on the relevant doc page?

Comment: i did really miss that one, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$stmt->store_result();` before getting the num_rows.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare
("SELECT username, password FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result(); //You need to store the results first
$stmt -> bind_result($returned_username, $returned_password);   
$stmt->fetch();

$row_count = $stmt -> num_rows;
echo $row_count;

echo $returned_username;
echo "<br />";
echo $returned_password;

$stmt -> close();   
$mysqli ->close();
```

Comment: Aah to late :-) Glad you have your solution!

Comment: Yeah indeed, Thanks for an answer anyway